# Perl Comparison

Tags: linux, perl, comparison

I'm creating a script in Perl that will takes photos from a camera and check to see if any new pictures have been taken. In Ubuntu I'm using gphoto2 to search the camera for the pictures then downloading any new picture. I've seen a couple of scripts online that come close to meeting my needs, but I'm running into the issue where the USB port needs to be reset after every gphoto2 request. The only issue I'm having now is, how do I save the output below into an array or a file that I can compare?

```
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/112EOS5D'.
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/113EOS5D'.
There are 3 files in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/114EOS5D'.
#1     IMG_0001.JPG               rd   347 KB image/jpeg
#2     IMG_0002.JPG               rd   342 KB image/jpeg
#3     IMG_0003.JPG               rd   336 KB image/jpeg
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/MISC'.
```

to this

```
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/112EOS5D'.
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/113EOS5D'.
There are 5 files in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM/114EOS5D'.
#1     IMG_0001.JPG               rd   347 KB image/jpeg
#2     IMG_0002.JPG               rd   342 KB image/jpeg
#3     IMG_0003.JPG               rd   336 KB image/jpeg
#4     IMG_0004.JPG               rd   348 KB image/jpeg
#5     IMG_0005.JPG               rd   342 KB image/jpeg
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/MISC'.
```

Here is what produces the code. the gphoto2 --list-files give the output and the ./reset is a simple c code that resets the usb port so gphoto2 can do it's thing.

```
sub main {
    while (1) {
    system("gphoto2 --list-files");
    system("./reset /dev/bus/usb/003/021");
    sleep 5;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why am i getting down votted?

Comment: I've not downvoted you so I can't speak for those who have, but I think your question will do better if you: a) show us the code you've already got (if any), b) tell us exactly what generated the first lot of output (this may be the same as a, it's not clear), and c) tell us how you generated the second lot of output (is this what gphoto2 does?). Given this lot, there's more chance you'll get a helpful answer!

Comment: @TayMoore To get the output from a command, use backticks/`qx` or the `open` command with `-|` mode. However, this question provides very little usable info; I have *no* idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: it's just compare the first log to the second log. I need to find the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are using some c code to produce the output and then you want to somehow get that output into a Perl script so you can compare the it with the output from the last time the code ran to know which files are new.

One way to do this would be to pipe the output of the c code into a text file and then have the c code run a Perl script that would load an array of the image file name from the last time the script ran, load the c output file that was just created, compare the files to see which ones are new, and then do whatever you are wanting to do with the new files.  At the end of the Perl script you'd have to modify the array of image file names so you'll have it the next time the Perl script runs, for comparison.

You can extract the file names from the output with a regular expression, and then just do an array comparison.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was going for. I actually wrote the code in perl. The script would call get the output from gphoto, which may or may not be c idk it's something I downloaded. I am going to put the output into a new text file then compare it to an old output file. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Okay, since it's all in Perl that should make it less complicated.  I would still just parse out the files names that are present in the output with a regular expression and then do a comparison on the which files have been added.